# Storing Entries in a Loop Under Certain Conditions

Tags: r, loops

I want to create a while loop that only keeps the next iteration if it is larger than all previous iterations. I tried to write the code for this loop like this:

```
library(dplyr)

list_results <- list()

for (i in 1:100000) {
  
    num_1_i 
    
    while (TRUE) {
      
        num_1_i <- rnorm(1,100,10)
        
      

        
        if ( num_1_i >  max(unlist(list_results))) break
    }
      
    inter_results_i <- data.frame(i, num_1_i)
    list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
}
```

When I inspect the results, this looks reasonable (i.e. every number is bigger than the previous number - but I still got this warning:

```
Warning message:
In max(unlist(list_results)) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

**Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?**

Comment: Do you get the warning just once? If so, it’s during the first iteration of the loop, when `list_results` is of length zero. To avoid the warning, simply check for an empty list before testing to see if the current result should be added. Testing for `I` equal to `1` should also work.

Comment: Do you want to always do 100000 iterations, drawing a random number every iteration but only saving it if it was larger than all previous stored/drawn (former implies latter) values? Or do you  want to keep going until you have 100000 saved values, no matter how long? Or do you want to possible exit the loop before that number of iterations?